# mocha test get timeout when await a new Promise which's executor is async and throw error inside

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

I'm using mocha for testing, when I code below, the test will get timeout:

```js
describe("myTest", () => {
  it("myTest-0", async () => {
    await new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
      throw new Error("this is error");
    });
  });
});
```

[image]

=========================================================

but if I remove new Promise executor's `async` prefix, the test will throw error immediately:

```js
describe("myTest", () => {
  it("myTest-0", () => {
    await new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
      throw new Error("this is error");
    });
  });
});
```

[image]

=========================================

why the first one get timeout instead of throwing error immediately?

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Comment: "*if I remove new Promise executor's async prefix*" - i think you removed the wrong `async` from your sample code. Please [edit] to fix